# Excel basic script that compares multiple cells from multiple spreadsheets

Tags: excel

I am looking for help with writing an excel basic script. What I would like to do is take a value from one spreadsheet (i.e if X=true) and then compare that with two different cells on another spreadsheet (essentially name/email and date) and then make a change to a cell within that spreadsheet.

I am very new to the world of excel scripts but am essentially trying to automate a checking-in process. When a person scans a QR code I've managed to use Power Automate to generate an excel file giving me their email and whether they are present

Now I want to automatically update multiple other spreadsheets provided the name/email matches and obviously update a specific cell depending on the date - does that make sense?

I've had a lot of fun getting to the stage I am at now, but now I really an stuck! :)

I have tried looking at various if present (excel header) = true scripts, but thats as far as I can get before I get confused as I am then comparing multiple excel sheets to find a matching email and then want to update a specific date - hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: Hello and welcome to S.O. please not that this is not a free coding service. That said, show us the code you have so far and explain the exact problem you are facing, we`ll be happy to help out. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Are the excel documents online, if so Power Automate maybe able to do this for you, but without sample date for each workbook and the expected results, it is not possible to advise on possible solutions or where to look for more guidance.

Comment: Hi guys thank you so much! I'm sorry if this isn't the right place to ask! I will go to power automate and see if that can help :) Thanks so much, and sorry once again for posting if its not appropriate!